# What should we do with an edit that includes something the OP wrote in the comments?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23139667) suggested edit from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56353482/testing-a-code-running-on-multiple-instancesprod-like-behaviour) post:

[image]

The proposer, user [cmoetzing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5778814/cmoetzing), includes the exact code that OP has provided after *cmoetzing* asked them about in the comment section:

[image]

My question here is if this should be accepted or not. I am relatively new to looking at suggested edits, and my overall occupation is to stay critical. In most cases I've seen so far suggesting something externally is considered "attempt to reply", but in this case the source is OP themselves. But they could just also have asked OP to include it themselves (which would be a reason to decline it as "attempt to reply").

The contribution as-is surely provides readability and accessibility, but it isn't of absolute necessity. I am just unsure as I've never seen such a case and would like to learn by hearing what the experienced feel regarding this edit.

Comment: Approve. It doesn't deviate from OP's intent nor it is an attempt to reply. If you aren't sure, click skip. I'd personally skip this and let OP review it.

Comment: Stack, read the answer in the dupe and you'll see how it applies perfectly.

Comment: @yivi Ah I see, well the title of the dupe is somewhat misleading as that small detail is very important.

Comment: It was not the easiest dup to find because of that exact issue, but I knew something existed since this is an oft asked question

Comment: What is *occopution*?

Answer (score 3):

The comment adds needed details to the question. Therefore this edit is appropriate.

> But they could just also have asked OP to include it themself

Sure, but that would've taken longer, and would've involved more work, ending up at the same in the end.